# AOSP Nougat build system - functionality to build just an module and create system.img

Tags: android, android-source, android-7.0-nougat, bsp

Till now i have been working upon AOSP kitkat and now i am moving to android nougat.
In kitkat AOSP when i needed to build an system app situated in /packages/apps/xyz_app , i was using "mmm" and "make snod" which were enough to build the system.img without needing to build the whole source.
Also if i wanted to do the runtime sync, i was using below commands,

1) mmm /packages/apps/xyz_app
2) adb sync
3) adb shell stop
4) adb shell start

which were time saver for me.

So, is the same functionality available for android nougat ?
If not is there any alternative to create system.img, if just an app changes (using any command), also an alternative to sync changes on the fly on device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This command is supported by android build system, in nougat and oreo, google does not change it. So you can use it as before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i will set up an environment and will check and will update here.